# Largest digit in 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Given an integer two-dimensional array `A[1..5, 1..5]`, find the largest `K` such that in any row of the array, there exists an element greater than or equal to `K`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File("output.txt"));

        // Create a 2D array to store the input data
        int[][] array = new int[5][5];

        // Read data from the input file into the 2D array
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    array[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }

        // Find the maximum K
        int maxK = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] > maxK) {
                    maxK = array[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        // Write the result to the output file
        out.println(maxK);
    }
}
```

I have written a program that incorrectly solves this problem, and I need help. As far as I understand the task, I need to find the threshold above which there are digits equal to or greater than this threshold, but I don't know how to solve it.

Here's a test case for verification that my code solves incorrectly:

input.txt:

```
 6  7  9  4  5
 7  0  2  5  6
 5  7 -7  1  7
 5  2  2  8  4
 1  3  3  4  5
```

Expected output:

```
5
```

However, my program gives the following output:
9

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Run your program under the debugger, step through it and think about what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `maxK` is the overall maximum of the array (ie of *all* elements). But for your task you have to find the maximum of each row. And `K` is then the minimum of those ...

```
int k = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
  int m = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
    int v = scanner.nextInt();
    if (v > m) m = v;  //find the maximum of the current row
  }
  if (m < k) k = m; //compare the maximum to the current k
}

out.println(k);
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very easy. All you need is to find the `max` number of each row and find the `min` value of all `max` numbers.

This problem can be solve with time `O(N)`.

```java
public static int findLargest(int[][] arr) {
    int k = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        int maxRow = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++)
            maxRow = Math.max(maxRow, arr[row][col]);

        k = Math.min(k, maxRow);
    }

    return k;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> *"... I have written a program that incorrectly solves this problem ..."*

To preface, make sure to close the *[Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Closeable.html)* objects.

A typical approach is to use the *[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)* *statement*.

```java
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))) {
    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream("output.txt")) {
        
    }
}
```

> *"... As far as I understand the task, I need to find the threshold above which there are digits equal to or greater than this threshold, but I don't know how to solve it. ..."*

Traverse *array*, and iterate on each element.

```java
// Find the maximum K
int maxK = array[0][0];
for (int[] r : array)
    for (int v : r) if (v >= maxK) maxK = v;
```

Here is the complete re-factor.

```java
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))) {
    // Create a 2D array to store the input data
    int[][] array = new int[5][5];

    // Read data from the input file into the 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            array[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }

    // Find the maximum K
    int maxK = array[0][0];
    for (int[] r : array)
        for (int v : r) if (v >= maxK) maxK = v;

    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream("output.txt")) {
        // Write the result to the output file
        out.println(maxK);
    }
}
```

For demonstration, here is an example using a *stream*.

```java
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")).useDelimiter("\\R")) {
    // Find the maximum K
    int maxK
        = scan.tokens()
              .mapToInt(x -> Stream.of(x.trim().split(" +"))
                                   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                                   .max()
                                   .getAsInt())
              .max()
              .getAsInt();

    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream("output.txt")) {
        // Write the result to the output file
        out.println(maxK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice refactoring, but still will give you the wrong answer. Ie the overall maximum of the array. OP already has this ...